# Problems with Python in Google App Engine - UTF-8 and ASCII

Tags: python, google-app-engine, utf-8, ascii

So for the past few days I've been trying to learn Python in App Engine. However, I've been encountering a number of problems with ASCII and UTF encoding. The freshest issue is as follows:

I have the following piece of code of a simplistic chatroom from the book 'Code in the Cloud'

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
import datetime


# START: MainPage
class ChatMessage(object):
def __init__(self, user, msg):
    self.user = user
    self.message = msg
    self.time = datetime.datetime.now()

def __str__(self):
    return "%s (%s): %s" % (self.user, self.time, self.message)

Messages = []

class ChatRoomPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    self.response.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/html"
    self.response.out.write("""
       <html>
         <head>
           <title>MarkCC's AppEngine Chat Room</title>
         </head>
         <body>
           <h1>Welcome to MarkCC's AppEngine Chat Room</h1>
           <p>(Current time is %s)</p>
       """ % (datetime.datetime.now()))
    # Output the set of chat messages
    global Messages
    for msg in Messages:
        self.response.out.write("<p>%s</p>" % msg)
    self.response.out.write("""
       <form action="" method="post">
       <div><b>Name:</b> 
       <textarea name="name" rows="1" cols="20"></textarea></div>
       <p><b>Message</b></p>
       <div><textarea name="message" rows="5" cols="60"></textarea></div>
       <div><input type="submit" value="Send ChatMessage"></input></div>
       </form>
     </body>
   </html>
   """)
 # END: MainPage    
 # START: PostHandler
def post(self):
    chatter = self.request.get("name")
    msg = self.request.get("message")
    global Messages
    Messages.append(ChatMessage(chatter, msg))
    # Now that we've added the message to the chat, we'll redirect
    # to the root page, which will make the user's browser refresh to
    # show the chat including their new message.
    self.redirect('/')        
# END: PostHandler




# START: Frame
chatapp = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', ChatRoomPage)])


def main():
run_wsgi_app(chatapp)

if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
# END: Frame
```

It works ok in English. However, the moment I add some non-standard characters all sorts of problems start

First of all, in order for the thing to be actually able to display characters in HTML I add meta tag - charset=UTF-8" etc

Curiously, if you enter non-standard letters, the program processes them nicely, and displays them with no issues. However, it fails to load if I enter any non-ascii letters to the web layout iteself withing the script. I figured out that adding utf-8 encoding line would work. So I added (# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-). This was not enough. Of course I forgot to save the file in UTF-8 format. Upon that the program started running.

That would be the good end to the story, alas....

It doesn't work

Long story short this code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
import datetime


# START: MainPage
class ChatMessage(object):
def __init__(self, user, msg):
    self.user = user
    self.message = msg
    self.time = datetime.datetime.now()

def __str__(self):
    return "%s (%s): %s" % (self.user, self.time, self.message)

Messages = []
class ChatRoomPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    self.response.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/html"
    self.response.out.write("""
       <html>
         <head>
           <title>Witaj w pokoju czatu MarkCC w App Engine</title>
           <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
         </head>
         <body>
           <h1>Witaj w pokoju czatu MarkCC w App Engine</h1>
           <p>(Dokladny czas Twojego logowania to: %s)</p>
       """ % (datetime.datetime.now()))
    # Output the set of chat messages
    global Messages
    for msg in Messages:
        self.response.out.write("<p>%s</p>" % msg)
    self.response.out.write("""
       <form action="" method="post">
       <div><b>Twój Nick:</b> 
       <textarea name="name" rows="1" cols="20"></textarea></div>
       <p><b>Twoja Wiadomość</b></p>
       <div><textarea name="message" rows="5" cols="60"></textarea></div>
       <div><input type="submit" value="Send ChatMessage"></input></div>
       </form>
     </body>
   </html>
   """)
# END: MainPage    
# START: PostHandler
def post(self):
    chatter = self.request.get(u"name")
    msg = self.request.get(u"message")
    global Messages
    Messages.append(ChatMessage(chatter, msg))
    # Now that we've added the message to the chat, we'll redirect
    # to the root page, which will make the user's browser refresh to
    # show the chat including their new message.
    self.redirect('/')        
# END: PostHandler




# START: Frame
chatapp = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', ChatRoomPage)])


def main():
run_wsgi_app(chatapp)

if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
# END: Frame
```

Fails to process anything I write in the chat application when it's running. It loads but the moment I enter my message (even using only standard characters) I receive

```
File "D:\Python25\lib\StringIO.py", line 270, in getvalue
self.buf += ''.join(self.buflist)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 64: ordinal not in       range(128)
```

error message. In other words, if I want to be able to use any characters within the application I cannot put non-English ones in my interface. Or the other way round, I can use non-English characters within the app only if I don't encode the file in utf-8. How to make it all work together?

Comment: If you've not already come across it, unicode bootcamp: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html . This is essential to understanding what's actually going on. Then look at the warning about unicode in the StringIO docs: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: @Thomas K. I see what you mean, and I understand the need and use of different encodings. As you see in the second example of the code I accounted for different charsets by adding lines such as # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- or the HTML charset meta tag. The thing I don't understand is how Python handles it all. Why Python demands me to constantly encode and decode things back nad forth, myself? How I can accomplish it in this example. I've been toying with various methods, including (unicode( s, "utf-8" )) and (.encode( "utf-8") with little success. Yes, I'm very inexperienced.

Comment: I don't know exactly what's going on with your application, but on lines 21 and 35, try making your strings start with `u"""`, so they are unicode strings. The problem is that you're trying to write out a mixture of encoded strings and unicode.

Comment: @Thomas K. Thank you for the linked article. It made me think that I was doing something in the wrong order. The line Messages.append(ChatMessage(chatter, msg)) should look like this:
Messages.append(ChatMessage(chatter.encode( "utf-8" ), msg.encode( "utf-8" ))) I would post this as an aswer but it seems I cannot, for at least 3 hours.

Comment: That will work, but it's better practice to store them as unicode strings and only encode when you're calling `self.response.out.write`.

Comment: You need to include the complete stacktrace. Also: The characters aren't "non standard" - unicode is a standard. And you shouldn't use a meta tag - set the encoding in the Content-Type header.

Comment: @Mathias: You’re right that this is all screwed up. The cure for all this is to 1) use normal Python 3 not the old legacy Python 2 stuff with its broken Unicode model and 2) set the encoding on the output stream so that you no longer have to do all that stupid explicit encoding to UTF-8 again and again and again and again and again, just like you rightly asked about but nobody answered you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your strings contain unicode characters, but they're not unicode strings, they're byte strings. You need to prefix each one with `u` (as in `u"foo"`) in order to make them into unicode strings. If you ensure all your strings are Unicode strings, you should eliminate that error.

You should also specify the encoding in the `Content-Type` header rather than a meta tag, like this:

```
self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
```

Note your life would be a lot easier if you used a templating system instead of writing HTML inline with your Python code.

Comment: Thanks. I will remember your advice.

Comment: @Mathias would find his life would be easier if he either used Python 3 at the very least  did a `from __future__ import unicode_literals`. He.encode("UTF-8") also.encode("UTF-8") needs.encode("UTF-8") to.encode("UTF-8") set.encode("UTF-8") the.encode("UTF-8") stream.encode("UTF-8") output.encode("UTF-8") encoding.encode("UTF-8") to.encode("UTF-8") avoid.encode("UTF-8") all.encode("UTF-8") this.encode("UTF-8") utterly.encode("UTF-8") stupid.encode("UTF-8") crap..encode("UTF-8")

Comment: @tchrist That would be good advice, except that he's using App Engine, which doesn't run Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

@Thomas K. 
Thank you for your guidance here. Thanks to you I was able to come up with, maybe - as you said - a little roudabout solution - so the credit for the answer should go to you. The following line of code:

```
Messages.append(ChatMessage(chatter, msg))
```

Should look like this:

```
Messages.append(ChatMessage(chatter.encode( "utf-8" ), msg.encode( "utf-8" )))
```

Basically I have to encode all the utf-8 string to ascii.