# UTF-8 Python issues with Google Datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, utf-8, ascii, google-cloud-datastore

I've been roaming around these forums asking questions about issues related to Python and UTF-8 encoding/decoding.

This time around I've stumbled upon something which initially seemed an easy problem.

In my previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7138797/problems-with-python-in-google-app-engine-utf-8-and-ascii) I asked how to ensure proper addition of UTF-8 strings to variables:

```
Messages.append(ChatMessage(chatter, msg))
```

The solution was something along those lines:

```
Messages.append(ChatMessage(chatter.encode( "utf-8" ), msg.encode( "utf-8" )))
```

Pretty simple.

However, now I am faced with the challenge to send the data to Google App Engine Datastore. The code from the book I was using (Code in the Cloud)looked as follows (I skipped the redundant parts):

```
#START: ChatMessage
class ChatMessage(db.Model):
    user = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    timestamp = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    message = db.TextProperty(required=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s (%s): %s" % (self.user, self.timestamp, self.message)
#END: ChatMessage

# START: PostHandler
class ChatRoomPoster(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        chatter = self.request.get("name")
        msgtext = self.request.get("message")
        msg = ChatMessage(user=chatter, message=msgtext)
        msg.put() #<callout id="co.put"/>
        self.redirect('/')        
# END: PostHandler
```

I thought that swaping a part of the PostHandler with the following bit:

```
msg = ChatMessage(user=chatter.encode( "utf-8" ), message=msgtext.encode( "utf-8" ))
```

... would do the trick. Unfortunately, that did not happen. I still keep getting

```
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~markcc-chatroom-one-pl/1.353054484690143927/pchat.py", line 147,      in post
msg = ChatMessage(user=chatter.encode( "utf-8" ), message=msgtext.encode( "utf-8" ))

 UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Naturally, I declared (# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-) statement and put:

```
self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
```

in the file. It does nothing to alleviate the issue.

As you can see I am not very well-versed in Python, and encoding/decoding problems are, for me, a bit of novelty. I would appreciate your assistance. If anyonone could explain to me where I went wrong in this case and what practices to use to avoid similar quandaries in the future? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`encode` turns unicode into bytes, and `decode` turns bytes into unicode. You have to be careful not to mix the two. Your error means either:

1. `chatter` or `msgtext` is already bytes, and you are trying to encode it. One of the worst 'features' of Python 2 is that it lets you do this - it tries to first *decode* the bytes using ascii (the most limited encoding), and then re-encode them with whatever you've asked for. This is fixed in Python 3, but you can't use that on App Engine.
2. App Engine expects to store unicode ([it does](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#str)). So you need to pass it a unicode string *without* encoding it. In fact, if your data is already in a bytestring, you would need to *decode* it before you can store it.

In short, the first thing to try is simply *not* calling `.encode` before you store the data.

(I may have pointed you to it before, but if not, please take the time to read [this article about unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html))